# JList selected item to String - Weird result: Donnees.Marques@3d5bac58

Tags: java, swing

I try this and the result is not the value of my item but a value like this Donnees.Marques@3d5bac58

```
listCategories.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String selectedCategories = listCategories.getSelectedValue().toString();
                System.out.println(selectedCategories);
            }
        });
```

Comment: That seems like you printing out some memory adress.

Comment: What is the type of variable `listCategories` does it store `Donnees.Marques` types of variables?

Answer (score 2):

Per default when you use the `.toString()` method on your own objects you are printing its memory address as a string. This is for the same reason that you compare two objects with `.equals()` and not `==`, as the default thing you're tampering with is the object memory address.

To fix this you need to override the super `Object`'s `toString` metod, like this:

```
public class ListModel
{

// ...

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String text = "I want to print this when I call listModel.toString()";

        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you said but how do I do

Comment: You add the `@Override` method (adjusted for what you want it to print) to the class of the object you have put into the list.

Answer (score 1):

The default renderer for a JList display the toString() implementation of the Object that you are adding to the list.

You need to create a custom renderer for your JList since you are using a custom Object.

Read the section on [How to Write a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more information and examples.

```
String selectedCategories = listCategories.getSelectedValue().toString();
System.out.println(selectedCategories);
```

If you want to display a value from your object then you need to do:

```
Donnes.Marques item = (Donnes.Margues)listCategories.getSelectedValue();
System.out.println(item.getSomeProperty());
```

Or you can override the toString() method of your Donne.Marquee class.

Comment: A cell renderer is the wrong way to address this;  it will break accessibility and keyboard navigation.  toString() is the correct way.

Comment: @VGR, `it will break accessibility and keyboard navigation` - you are correct, see [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for the better approach, that I usually recommend. `toString() is the correct way.` - it is the easiest way, not the correct way for a general class. The toString() method should not be used this way, unless you create a special class where this is the sole purpose of the class. See  [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this.

```
      DefaultListModel listModel=new DefaultListModel();
        jList1.setModel(listModel);
       int index = jList1.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
       String classFromList =listModel.getElementAt(index).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, You should override toString() method in your class. 
Example

```
MyObject myObj = listCategories.getSelectedValue();
```

then

```
public class MyObject {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int age;

    public MyObject() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // write your own parametrs like this : 
        return firstName+" "+lastName;

    }

}
```